# Loading .mp3 files with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm facing a problem with loading .mp3 files with Nuxt.JS (Vue.js)...

I've tried to load the file without an specific loader and webpack tells that he need one specific loader for the file and when i added the url-loader in nuxt.config.js file:

```
 build: {
/*
** Run ESLint on save
*/
extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
  if (isDev && isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    })

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav)$/i,
      loader: 'url-loader'
    })

  }
}
```

throws the error:

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'middleware' of undefined
```

Somebody have used another loaders in Nuxt.Js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `file-loader` instead of `url-loader`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work yet :'(

Comment: that error doesnt look like its releated to mp3.

Comment: What Webpack version are you using?

Comment: I'm using  `webpack@3.12.0`

Comment: Can you put a quick sample project of your issue on glitch.com (Nuxtjs.org uses this tool for demo/examples)? By the looks of it the issue has to do with the way you're importing it on the page or layout component, causing it to throw the error. It's difficult to say for sure without the big picture

Answer (score 6):

From Nuxt.js official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/webpack-audio-files/

```
export default {
  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you just have to use the file-loader in your webpack config :

```
{
  test: /\.mp3$/,
  include: '/path/to/directory',
  loader: 'file-loader'
}
```

Can you share your config file ?

Instead of import directly in javascript, I recommend you to load your file with a generic [resource loader](https://github.com/englercj/resource-loader).