# Dynamically load .mp3s in Vue.js+Nuxt.js on mounted()

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, webpack-file-loader

I'm tying to follow [the official nuxt.js documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/configuration/#extend-webpack-to-load-audio-files) to dynamically load dozens of .mp3 files as the user progresses through a quiz.I've set up my config file as follows:

nuxt.config.js (Nuxt v2.15.8):

```js
  build: {
    extend ( config, ctx ) {
      // Might be used for loading media files
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

**This works:**

```js
import audioFile from '~/assets/audio/sfx_Q1_1.mp3';

// Outputs /_nuxt/assets/audio/sfx_Q1_1.mp3, and the file plays as expected
console.log(audioFile);
```

Using an `import` statement works, and it gives me the correct asset path. The problem is that I need dozens of mp3s with `sfx_Q#_#.mp3` format, so I need a more dynamic approach.

**This doesn't work:**

```js
mounted() {
    let audioURL = `~/assets/audio/sfx_Q${this.qID}_${this.aID}.mp3`;
    let audio = require(audioURL);
    console.log(audio);
}
```

With this approach, my app crashes and I get `Cannot find module '~/assets/audio/sfx_Q1_1.mp3'`, even though it's exactly the same path as the version that worked with the `import` statement.

[image]

**This also works**

```vue
<audio v-bind:src="require(`~/assets/audio/sfx_Q${qID}_${aID}.mp3`).default"></audio>
```

**...but this doesn't work**

```vue
<audio v-bind:src="require(getAudioURL()).default"></audio>
// ... //
getAudioURL() {
    return `~/assets/audio/sfx_Q${this.qID}_${this.aID}.mp3`;
}
```

... I get the same `Cannot find module` error. Why does the import break when the file path is generated dynamically inside a method? I've tried with `@` symbol as well, to no avail. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410362/loading-mp3-files-with-nuxt-js) had the same issue, but I've tried exactly the solutions suggested, and it doesn't help.